Nextjs google site verification with next-intl
I am using Nextjs + next-intl. I now need google site verification. I chose to add meta, but it was unsuccessful because mydomain.com will automatically jump to /en/ or /zh/ route depending on the language because app/page.tsx has below code:
export default function RootPage() {
  redirect('/en');
}

I tried adding below code to app/layout.tsx
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  verification: {
    google: '...',
  },
};

And then clicked the Google search console verification button, but it was unsuccessful. I tried adding meta to app/[locale]/layout.tsx and it succeeded, but it can only be verified when the URL is the Language. , but I want to verify the URL without language routing, am I wrong? I don’t need this? I just need to add meta to the two locales respectively?
